# External disk not accessible

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, external-hard-drive, mount

My WD Elements external disk connected via USB 3.0 cable is not accessible. I tried it with two versions of Windows and with Ubuntu 16.04 kernel 4.6.0.

The disk was working some days ago. Then, during an error while copying data, the disk was disconnected. After this, it did no longer work. It does not show up as a device.

Did some diagnostics with Ubuntu:

- plugged it off, waited several minutes and plugged it on again
- used every available USB slot
- used two different cables, both of which are working for other devices
- `mount` does not list the device
- `sudo fdisk -l` does not list the device
- the disks program from the Ubuntu GUI does not list the device
- `lsblk` does not list the device
- `sudo blkid` does not list the device
- `lsusb` does not list the device
- `usb-devices` does not list the device
- also tried mounting the device with [SystemRescueCD](https://www.system-rescue-cd.org/Download)

I also did this (with no success): `sudo apt-get install mtp-tools mtpfs`

the output of `sudo lshw`

```
*-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.6.0-040600-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 4.06
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=5000Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: Mass storage device
                   product: Elements 10A8
                   vendor: Western Digital
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: usb@2:4
                   logical name: scsi0
                   version: 10.42
                   serial: 5758353145343355414B3037
                   capabilities: usb-3.00 scsi emulated scsi-host
                   configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=896mA speed=5000Mbit/s
                 *-disk UNCLAIMED
                      description: SCSI Disk
                      physical id: 0.0.0
                      bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
```

From `/var/log/syslog`

```
Jul 25 16:48:24 my-pc kernel: [28431.161131] usb 2-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
Jul 25 16:48:24 my-pc kernel: [28431.177636] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=10a8
Jul 25 16:48:24 my-pc kernel: [28431.177649] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jul 25 16:48:24 my-pc kernel: [28431.177657] usb 2-4: Product: Elements 10A8
Jul 25 16:48:24 my-pc kernel: [28431.177664] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Western Digital
Jul 25 16:48:24 my-pc kernel: [28431.177669] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 57***4B3037
Jul 25 16:48:24 my-pc kernel: [28431.189531] usb-storage 2-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Jul 25 16:48:24 my-pc kernel: [28431.189680] scsi host0: usb-storage 2-4:1.0
Jul 25 16:48:24 my-pc mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4"
Jul 25 16:48:24 my-pc mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 8 was not an MTP device
Jul 25 16:48:25 my-pc kernel: [28432.190195] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       Elements 10A8    1042 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Jul 25 16:48:25 my-pc kernel: [28432.191584] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Jul 25 16:48:25 my-pc kernel: [28432.194768] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
Jul 25 16:48:36 my-pc dbus[844]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Jul 25 16:48:36 my-pc systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Jul 25 16:48:36 my-pc dbus[844]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jul 25 16:48:36 my-pc systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Jul 25 16:49:01 my-pc kernel: [28433.197394] ......
Jul 25 16:49:01 my-pc kernel: [28468.407136] usb 2-4: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
Jul 25 16:49:06 my-pc kernel: [28473.427080] usb 2-4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Jul 25 16:49:06 my-pc kernel: [28473.530957] usb 2-4: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
Jul 25 16:49:11 my-pc kernel: [28478.551421] usb 2-4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Jul 25 16:49:12 my-pc kernel: [28478.711675] usb 2-4: USB disconnect, device number 8
Jul 25 16:49:12 my-pc kernel: [28478.711682] ready
Jul 25 16:49:12 my-pc kernel: [28478.719239] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jul 25 16:49:12 my-pc kernel: [28478.719250] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
Jul 25 16:49:12 my-pc kernel: [28478.719274] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is on
Jul 25 16:49:12 my-pc kernel: [28478.719282] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 8e 40 c3 d0
Jul 25 16:49:12 my-pc kernel: [28478.719300] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
Jul 25 16:49:12 my-pc kernel: [28478.719307] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jul 25 16:49:12 my-pc kernel: [28478.720016] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jul 25 16:49:12 my-pc kernel: [28478.720023] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
Jul 25 16:49:12 my-pc kernel: [28478.720104] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Jul 25 16:49:12 my-pc kernel: [28478.720111] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
Jul 25 16:49:12 my-pc kernel: [28478.720133] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
Jul 25 16:49:12 my-pc systemd-udevd[13675]: Process '/lib/udev/hdparm' failed with exit code 2.
Jul 25 16:49:12 my-pc systemd-udevd[13675]: inotify_add_watch(9, /dev/sda, 10) failed: No such file or directory
```

I also added the following line to `/lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules`:

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="1058", ATTR{idProduct}=="10a8", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", MODE="660", GROUP="disk", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1", TAG+="uaccess"
```

With that line, an entry in the `nautilus` file browser for this disk is there, but when clicking on it, it shows:

```
Unable to access "Elements 10A8"
No MTP devices found
```

From `/var/log/syslog` (after adding the line in `69-libmtp.rules`)

```
Jul 25 16:34:07 my-pc kernel: [27573.854775] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
Jul 25 16:34:07 my-pc kernel: [27574.350270] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
Jul 25 16:34:07 my-pc kernel: [27574.535870] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=10a8
Jul 25 16:34:07 my-pc kernel: [27574.535883] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jul 25 16:34:07 my-pc kernel: [27574.535890] usb 1-4: Product: Elements 10A8
Jul 25 16:34:07 my-pc kernel: [27574.535896] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Western Digital
Jul 25 16:34:07 my-pc kernel: [27574.535901] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 57***4B3037
Jul 25 16:34:07 my-pc kernel: [27574.536926] usb-storage 1-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Jul 25 16:34:07 my-pc kernel: [27574.537183] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-4:1.0
Jul 25 16:34:07 my-pc org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1729]: ** (gvfsd:1801): WARNING **: dbus_mount_reply: Error from org.gtk.vfs.Mountable.mount(): No MTP devices found
Jul 25 16:34:07 my-pc gnome-session[1872]: Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Jul 25 16:34:08 my-pc kernel: [27574.674010] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 17
Jul 25 16:34:08 my-pc kernel: [27575.002417] usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
Jul 25 16:34:08 my-pc kernel: [27575.342331] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
Jul 25 16:34:08 my-pc kernel: [27575.528821] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=10a8
Jul 25 16:34:08 my-pc kernel: [27575.528833] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jul 25 16:34:08 my-pc kernel: [27575.528841] usb 1-4: Product: Elements 10A8
Jul 25 16:34:08 my-pc kernel: [27575.528847] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Western Digital
Jul 25 16:34:08 my-pc kernel: [27575.528852] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 57***4B3037
Jul 25 16:34:08 my-pc kernel: [27575.529755] usb-storage 1-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Jul 25 16:34:08 my-pc kernel: [27575.530031] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-4:1.0
Jul 25 16:34:08 my-pc org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1729]: ** (gvfsd:1801): WARNING **: dbus_mount_reply: Error from org.gtk.vfs.Mountable.mount(): No MTP devices found
Jul 25 16:34:08 my-pc gnome-session[1872]: Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Jul 25 16:34:09 my-pc kernel: [27576.531222] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       Elements 10A8    1042 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Jul 25 16:34:09 my-pc kernel: [27576.533070] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Jul 25 16:34:09 my-pc kernel: [27576.535648] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
Jul 25 16:34:32 my-pc org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1729]: ** (gvfsd:1801): WARNING **: dbus_mount_reply: Error from org.gtk.vfs.Mountable.mount(): No MTP devices found
Jul 25 16:34:45 my-pc kernel: [27577.538470] .....
Jul 25 16:34:45 my-pc kernel: [27612.368955] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 19
Jul 25 16:34:45 my-pc kernel: [27612.368982] ready
Jul 25 16:34:45 my-pc kernel: [27612.376377] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jul 25 16:34:45 my-pc kernel: [27612.376398] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
Jul 25 16:34:45 my-pc kernel: [27612.376442] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Jul 25 16:34:45 my-pc kernel: [27612.376455] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
Jul 25 16:34:45 my-pc kernel: [27612.376938] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
Jul 25 16:34:45 my-pc kernel: [27612.376951] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jul 25 16:34:45 my-pc kernel: [27612.380000] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jul 25 16:34:45 my-pc kernel: [27612.380018] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
Jul 25 16:34:45 my-pc kernel: [27612.380097] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
Jul 25 16:34:45 my-pc kernel: [27612.516074] usb 2-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
Jul 25 16:34:45 my-pc systemd-udevd[12892]: Process '/lib/udev/hdparm' failed with exit code 2.
Jul 25 16:34:45 my-pc systemd-udevd[12892]: inotify_add_watch(9, /dev/sda, 10) failed: No such file or directory
Jul 25 16:34:50 my-pc kernel: [27617.532205] usb 2-4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Jul 25 16:34:51 my-pc kernel: [27617.636181] usb 2-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
Jul 25 16:34:56 my-pc kernel: [27622.652911] usb 2-4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
```

Is there any software that can restore data from a drive that cannot be mounted/found? (DDrescue, Testdisk, photorec, ...)

Any advice is very welcome!

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! You will probably get better expertise on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com).

Comment: thanks, @ubashu. I think I have enough answers and will go for the professional company...

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to hear about the situation! Try the following:

- See if it's recognized in Device Manager and [Disk Management](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=zBZFVo).
- Try checking if the drive is visible with [WD Data Lifeguard Diagnostic tool](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=ypucmE).

Also:

- See if the drive visible in the BIOS
- Try the drive on other computers
- Check for the vibration to see if the disk is spinning inside the enclosure

If the data is very important your best shot would be contacting a data recovery company for the highest chances of getting your data back, but have in mind that their services can be costly.

Using third-party data recovery tools may be effective but it's also risky as they can further corrupt your data and any attempts to test or recovery the drive may further damage it if it has hardware problems.

Comment: thanks for the advice. unfortunately it did not bring any success.
Disk Management did not list the device and the Device Manager (Windows) had an entry but I wasn't able to bring the device to life...

 `WD Data Lifeguard Diagnostic tool` did not list the device, so I wasn't able to run any tests on it.

The BIOS is not showing the device. It will even not boot, if the device is plugged in before powering on the PC.

Also tried other computers. No success.

The disk is rotating and making noise. I guess I have to go for the recovery company.

Comment: Since the drive can't be seen in any of those places and with any of the Linux commands on multiple computers with multiple cables then data recovery companies seem like the safest bet in this case. 
Have you checked DiskPart -> List Disk if the drive is displayed there? (I doubt it would make any difference)

Comment: jap, I have also checked that. not listed. thanks!